# Section of Cards with Go to page option

Tags: usability, design, cards

I am designing the section of cards to show the status in the dashboard screen. I am showing only 5 cards, then I would like to provide the link to go to another page to see complete list of statuses.
How to provide the Go to Page link in the cards section?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The common pattern is the <kbd>Show more</kbd> or <kbd>Load more</kbd> button, regardless of whether those results are on the same page or on another page.

[image]

<sub>*[Image source](https://planet4.greenpeace.org/story/13448/release-v2-67/)*</sub>